# How can I highlight a cell if its value is greater or lesser than the previous value from that column that's greater than 0?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I record the current prices for some products I'm interested in.
The headers are the product names and the index are timestamps, each cell contains a price if the product is in stock at the time, or "0" if it isn't.

Basically what I need is a formula I can apply to the entire spreadsheet that can compare the value of a cell to the most recent, non zero value from that same column, so that I can easily tell if prices have changed.

In the screenshot below I want the cell with the "4958.13" value to be filled red so I can tell the price for that product went up:

[image]

I need one formula for price increase and another one for price drops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formula in CF for price increments:

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1>0),A$1:A1)<A2)*(A2<>0)
```

for price decrements:

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1>0),A$1:A1)>A2)*(A2<>0)*(SUM(A$1:A1)<>0)
```

Apply to exact range.

[image]

Comment: The increments formula is working perfectly, but the decrement formula is formatting cells that it shouldn't. It's like it's highlighting cells just because the price went from "0" (out of stock) to something, I need the formula not to take into account zero values. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/cjuN0xW.png Thanks.

Comment: @lucassilvas1 I corrected formula for decrements. See edit.

Comment: I can't tell you how thankful I am @basic , I had been trying to solve this for hours before you answered. It's working perfectly now.